# GitHub: terminology: create pull request vs. open pull request

Tags: github, terminology, pull-request

Is there a difference between *creating a pull request* and *opening a pull request*?

Example of some phrases with *create a pull request*:

1. *Create a pull request* to propose and collaborate on changes to a repository.
2. You can specify which branch you'd like to merge your changes into when you *create your pull request*.
3. To *create a draft pull request*, use the drop-down and select *Create Draft Pull Request*.

Example of some phrases with *open a pull request*:

1. To *open a pull request* in a public repository, you must have write access to the head or the source branch.
2. Pull *requests can only be opened* between two branches that are different.
3. Once a *pull request is opened*, you can discuss and review the potential changes with collaborators.

P.S. In my view after *creating a pull request* it becomes:

1. Created.
2. Its state automatically becomes `open`.

Logically meaning that:

1. First of all a pull request must be *created*.
2. Then a pull request can be *opened* (its state is `open`) or *closed* (its state is `closed`) as many times as needed.

The consequence is that technically speaking *open a pull request* does not mean *create a pull request*.

Comment: Note, by the way, that none of these are *Git* things: they're GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, etc. Each hosting site has its own special quirks around these things (that most people can mostly ignore, fortunately).

Comment: @torek, thanks for the information! I've changed `git` to `GitHub`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Create a pull request* and *Open a pull request* mean the same but just use different verbs to indicate the creation of a PR(pull request). The only confusion that you have is due to `open` being one of the states of a PR.

When you say

> Logically meaning that:
>
> First of all a pull request must be created.
>
> Then a pull request can be opened (its state is open) or closed (its
>   state is closed) as many times as needed.

it doesn't necessarily mean that step 1 is creation and step 2 is opening of a PR, but actually when a PR is created or opened it has `open` as its `state` by default. The `state` is GitHub's internal construct to manage the state of a PR, ie if it's `open` or `closed` (`closed` can mean the PR is either **just closed** or **merged**).

- An open PR can be **closed** or **merged**, thereby changing its `state` from `open` to `closed`
- A PR which is closed (and not merged) can be **reopened** thereby changing its state from `closed` to `open`.

So technically speaking, *open a pull request* and *create a pull request* mean the same. Opening a PR which is closed and not yet merged is meant by *Reopening a pull request*.

Comment: the phrase `when a PR is created or opened it has open as its state by default` means that `when a PR is created` it `automatically becomes opened`, because `its state automatically becomes open`. Therefore, it is true that `open a pull request and create a pull request means the same`. Ok, it's clear now! One other terminology related question: why the opened state is named `open` and not `opened`?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no practical difference.

A pull request opened or created means there is a source branch and a destination branch (in the same repo or an upstream repository), which triggers a query for a maintainer to accept/comment or reject said pull request.

Even in GitLab (where the term is "Merge Request", not "Pull Request"), you would see:

> Once committed and pushed, you can click on the Create Merge Request button to open the New Merge Request page.